# Calling a method from a user control to a routed event in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone help me on this problem
I have a wpf application with one Window and one User Controls.

User Control: InventoryMenu
Window: MenuView

I created a routed event on my InventoryMenu:

```
NewImage.AddHandler(Image.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(First_Click1));
```

Now on my First_Click1 method, I am calling on a method from MenuView

```
private void First_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{  
    MenuView menu = new MenuView();  
    menu.showInventoryView();  
}
```

Now from MenuView:

```
public void showInventoryView()
{  
    Inventory inventoryView = new Inventory();  
    ChildView.Children.Clear();
    ChildView.Children.Add(inventoryView);  
    MessageBox.Show("I was called");  
}
```

The problem is that the method was called but the view was not shown?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your ChildView here ?

Comment: First of all show MenuView window by calling MenuView.Show().. then try it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set `invertoryView.Visible = true;` or `inventoryView.SetVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no Children Property for Window. Window is a ContentControl and has only 
one Child.
You can do it in xaml very easy. Here is some example how you can do it :

```
<Window x:Class="TestNamespace.MenuView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNamespace"
    Title="MenuView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <local:InventoryMenu/>
</Window>
```

Where local is your Local Namespace where your UserControl is placed. And now the child of the Window is your UserControl. If you want more than one UserControl in the Window you can say that the Child of Window is a Panel like Grid or StackPanel and place your UserControls in the Panels.